# What is the difference between the Point Spread Function and Sampling Aperture?

Tags: sampling

I've been told that the point spread function of a pixel is its distribution of intensity, while the sampling aperture of a pixel is its distribution of sensitivity. I'm a little unsure of what the difference between intensity and sensitivity is. It sounds like the former deals with how a pixel is displayed, while the latter deals with how it is captured. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds correct to me. The point-spread function indicates how the intensity of a point source is spread among multiple pixels in an image. In an imaging sensor, the sampling aperture of a particular pixel indicates how it responds to intensity from points in space as a function of the spatial offset from the pixel's center.

Comment: Just to confirm, when you say "how it responds to intensity", you mean, for example, if the sampling aperture followed a Gaussian distribution, the further away a point is from the center, the less intensity it will have?

Comment: Right. If there was a point source out in space, then the amount of intensity that the sensor would report for the pixel would follow a Gaussian curve as a function of the offset from the center of the pixel's field of view.